# build google-vr sdk with script prompt : script class layout is incompatible between the editor and the player

Tags: google-vr

I want to build google-vr sdk in unity with script.

so i wrote a AndroidBuild.cs script. core code below here:

```
[MenuItem("Build/ExportAndroidProject", false,0)]
static void ExportAndroidProject()
{
    BuildPlayerOptions buildPlayerOptions = new BuildPlayerOptions();
    //buildPlayerOptions.scenes = new[] { "Assets/RollBall/Scenes/MiniGame.unity" };
    buildPlayerOptions.scenes = new[] { "Assets/GoogleVR/Demos/Scenes/VideoDemo.unity" };
    buildPlayerOptions.locationPathName = "../tmp_android_projects";
    buildPlayerOptions.target = BuildTarget.Android;
    buildPlayerOptions.options = BuildOptions.AcceptExternalModificationsToPlayer;
    setAndroidSdkPath();
    setAndroidKeyStore();
    setOtherPlayerSettings();
    string buildResult=BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(buildPlayerOptions);
    Console.WriteLine("============> build result: " + buildResult);
}
```

but when i build it fails. it prompt that:

```
Error building player because script class layout is incompatible between the editor and the player.
```

there many errors like this:

```
Type '[Assembly-CSharp]Xxx' has an extra field 'xxx' of type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' in the player and thus can't be serialized
```

example:

```
Type '[Assembly-CSharp]DemoInputManager' has an extra field 'controllerMain' of type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' in the player and thus can't be serialized
```